# ActiveAdmin: not picking up new column added to table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, activeadmin

I have a new column in my production db called `start_dates`. I know it is in the remote database, as when I run `heroku pg:psql` and then and then `\dt` `\d programs` I see the column in the DB.

However when I access my ActiveAdmin account by going to the `/admin` path on my production URL, I do not see the new column added to the table there.

I know that I added the new column in my `app/admin/programs.rb` file and that it has successfully been pushed to heroku.

not really sure what other steps to follow.

Answer (score 1):

simply needed to run `heroku restart` for ActiveAdmin to pickup the changes.